# Second set of Sibelius 7 lyrics with repeat bar to midi?

Tags: software, sibelius, lyrics, repeats

In music sometimes a line is repeated with the repeat bar ||: :||. I'm using Sibelius and it doesn't seem to understand the repeat bar when it creates midi's with lyrics. It jumbles the text of the lyrics mixing the first and second line. Could someone tell me how to split the lyric lines and do proper repeats automatically?

This is what it looks like now:
[image: bar of repeated music with two lines of lyrics]

Comment: You should post this question at the Sibelius help forum. http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3

Comment: @WheatWilliams that's great that you suggest the Sibelius help forum for the OP. I have to say though, as a daily Sibelius user, I find their site a bit difficult to navigate; I much prefer the way this site works, and the fact that users are music-buffs, not just Sibelius users. I just wanted to check, Sibelius questions/answers are on topic, right…?

Comment: @caseyr547 I assume you know about how to put repeat bars in a Sibelius file and how to create line 1 and line 2 lyrics. I have just replicated the problem you are having, by saving as MIDI with lyrics from Sibelius (didn't know you could do that, so I've learnt something today!) and then reopening in Sibelius. For me, the lyrics for the first repeat come out fine, but then I get both sets of lyrics for the second repeat. Anyway, I'm trying to find a solution...

Comment: Yes, Sibelius questions are on-topic here. And yes, the Sibelius help forum is very hard to navigate. But a lot of Sibelius experts read and post on the Sibelius help forum frequently. It's a good place to go for Sibelius users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I scoured the web trying to find answers, but had no luck. After a bit of lateral thinking I have found a solution for you…

Select all of your Line 1 Lyrics (on Mac I click on the first syllable of the line and press shift-cmd-A). Then open the Inspector (right click **on the lyric text** and select Inspector). Then uncheck the "2" box under "Play on pass:" (which is itself under "Playback"). To be absolutely safe, you could uncheck all except the "1" box, but this seems like overkill.

[image]

This seemed to work fine when I Exported as MIDI and then reopened in Sibelius.  It's worth noting that you can also Export as MusicXML files, depending upon which program you want to open the file in. And, of course, an absolutely safe way to get around these problems is to simply enter music with no repeats, but instead written out in full!

Thanks to @Wheat Williams for Sibelius forum advice.

Comment: ok but uh it didnt have that option and i dont know what to do this is what it looks like http://uploading.com/e13df17d/the-lord-our-God-opt and this is what it makes in my copy of sib http://uploading.com/493398m8/thelordourgod-mid

Comment: Okay, I just opened your file (what is an .opt file BTW?!) Both your lines of lyrics are inputed using "Lyrics line 1". The lower line of lyrics (for the repeat) should use "Lyrics line 2". What option couldn't you find? The Inspector…?

Comment: opt is photoscore a another program from the people who make sib

Comment: Of course… Anyway, which option couldn't you find?

Comment: it doesnt show any option to change lyrics line

Comment: when i do inspector for the notes it does but not for the lyrics

Comment: Ummm, well mine does. Just try this… Select any bit of your lyrics, then press shift-cmd-I. (ctrl-shift-I on PC)

Comment: BTW, Lyrics Line 2 are inputed by clicking on a note and selecting "Lyrics Line 2" from the Text menu.

Comment: ok give me a min i just got everything on lyrics line two

Comment: Okay, I reckon you need to re-input your lyrics one line at a time, then you'll be fine.

Comment: no all you have to do is select the second line cut it then press cmd alt l and then ctr v over and over again until all the lyrics are in the write place it ques up the words one by one

Comment: http://uploading.com/f67b8bed/capturemusic2-PNG

Comment: 7.5 looks like you describe 7.0 does not

Answer (score 1):

All text in Sibelius has a Text Style which defines font, size and position.  Yours is all 'Lyrics Line 1'.   'Lyrics Line 2' has a different vertical position.  Use it!